# Postgresql: pass variable to varchar column in update query?

Tags: postgresql, datagrip

I have the following query:

```
update car set name=${carName} where id=${carId};
```

`carName` is a variable in this case I set to string value `myCarName`.

When I run this in DataGrip I get:

`[42703] ERROR: column "myCarName" does not exist`

What syntax do I need to follow to be able to run this query and set car.name column (varchar) to the value found in `carName`?

if I try to quote it, then it won't recognize the variable:
[image]

Comment: I tried that... but then it won't treat it as a variable and I can't pass in a value...

Comment: I see, quoting it when I enter the variable... that does work. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One needs to quote parameter value inside *Parameters* popup

[image]